# expose non-OData service methods in OData controller

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I need to expose a regular service method on an OData service controller. My method is correctly picked up at runtime, and executes fine as far as I could debug, but the browser is getting a 406 status code with no response body.  Here is the simplified code:

```
[RoutePrefix("odata/contracts")]
public class ContractsController : EntitySetController<Contract, int>
{
    private readonly IDataService dataService;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="dataService"></param>
    public ContractsController(IDataService dataService)
    {
        this.dataService = dataService;
    }

    [Route("WithItem")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Contract> GetContractsByItem(string catalogNumber, string vendorName)
    {
        var result = dataService.GetContractsWithItem(catalogNumber, vendorName).ToList();
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I request the following url in Chrome or Fiddler (`http://myserver/SoaRefImplOData/odata/contracts/WithItem?catalogNumber=abc&vendorName=3M`), I got the 406 status code.

So are regular Web Api methods not supposed to be mixed with OData controllers? I am using Web Api 2.1. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Web API 2.2 includes support for functions: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2014/03/13/getting-started-with-asp-net-web-api-2-2-for-odata-v4-0.aspx